# Как среди списка найти имя по ключевым словам?

Tags: python, строки, поиск

Если немного вопрос не понятен, извините, не понял, как правильно можно его задать. Суть в чём. Как можно реализовать поиск имени человека. Пример, как всё должно выглядеть. Мне нужно среди списка найти человека Диму Калашников (пример), я пишу команду: /поиск Дима Ка, и чтобы результат выдавал вот так:

Вот, что я нашёл:

1. Дима Калинин
2. Дима Кадиваров
3. Дима Калашников
   4.. и т.д
   9.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: если коротко, то брать длину фразы "Дима Ка" и сравнивать в других словах такую же длину, и если она равна Диме Ка, то вывести ее, это грубо

Comment: можно воспользоваться методом find() для каждого элемента списка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если по-взрослому, то я рекомендовал бы использовать алгоритм soundex, и модуль fonetika (`pip install fonetika`).

Сам код может выглядеть так:

```
from fonetika.soundex import RussianSoundex
soundex = RussianSoundex(cut_result=True, seq_cutted_len=4, code_vowels=True)

l = ['Колашников', 'Федоров', 'Киркоров', 'Криворуков','Иванов', 'Калашников', 'Петров', 'калашов', 'Циглер', 'калашников', 'Ватсон']

def snd_match(l: list, a: str) -> list:
    snd_heap = [(soundex.transform(x),x) for x in l]
    return [x[1] for x in snd_heap if (soundex.transform(a)[:len(a)+1] in x[0])]
```

проверяем:

```
print(snd_match(l, 'Ка')) #['Колашников', 'Калашников', 'калашов', 'калашников']
print(snd_match(l, 'Кол')) # ['Колашников', 'Калашников', 'калашов', 'калашников']
print(snd_match(l, 'Колашов')) # ['Колашников', 'Калашников', 'калашов', 'калашников']
print(snd_match(l, 'Киплинг')) # []
print(snd_match(l, 'Трамп')) # []
```